# intinite locking mysql query with message supremumpseido-record

Tags: mysql

I've got a Problem with an insert. You see in the graphic that a mysql-thread acquired a lock. This thread does not occur in the regular process list (I know it has not to be 100% in sync but it should at this point at least stand on sleep, as I would expect)

No other `INSERT` was possible in the affected table and this thread lastet about an hour.

[image: Image showing the problem]

You can notice, that this thread also has no actual query running.. but still has the lock. After killing it, everything worked fine... it was an regular insert, nothing fancy with joins, inner selects or complex data. What phenomena could cause this (also not as deadlock detected) infinite lock? Anyone could imagine what did happen there?

Additional Infos...

- it was an RDS instance with MySQL 5.6.21.
- In the Process List was nothing found that actually affected the FK (no other query then the regular Inserts on the affected able and some queries on tables that does not have anything to do with the affected table)

Comment: I also thought about that... did not finde anything according to thi, it must be a ridiculous rare case if it is a bug

Comment: I had a similar problem some months until it was fixed. I wrote a script, which search such lockings and kills them, but to try a other version would be better